# Retrofit upload Base64 string as a Field (8MB) takes 4 minutes

Tags: java, android, post, base64, retrofit2

I am trying to send the converted file (Base64 - String) as a parameter in POST, the file is about 8 MB, but sending takes about 4 minutes. Is there a way to speed up?

Interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("upload")
Call<Upload> upload(@Field("CONTENT") String content);
```

Retrofit instance:

```
public class RetrofitClientInstance {

private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static OkHttpClient client;

public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(String url) {
    if (retrofit == null && !url.isEmpty()) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();

        retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}}
```

Call:

```
 private void upload(){
    Api api = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance(SharedUtils.SERVER_URL).create(Api.class);

    Call<Upload> request = api.upload(getBase64FromFile());

    request.enqueue(new Callback<Upload>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Upload> call, Response<Upload> response) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Upload> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to compress your file or image before uploading, because it would take so much time to make it done

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using enqueue() method of retrofit which is an asynchronous way of executing the code and you have registered callbacks to these methods on successful execution you will receive the call inside onResponse() method but on failure, you will get control inside the onFailure() method.

This will spawn a thread of execution from the daemon thread which creates another thread of execution you may never know when will this thread gets executed based on OS priority.

Use execute() method to execute this in a synchronous manner and then check the response time it would give a proper result.